How do I correctly suppress an unused variable warning in Kotlin?
I tried to suppress a warning using a couple of different methods, but I ended up with this one:
class RotationGestureDetector(
    @Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") private val context: Context, // Accepting Context for consistency
    private val listener: OnRotationGestureListener
)

This gives the following warnings:
Warning:(35, 16) Redundant suppression
Warning:(35, 47) Property 'context' is never used

I also tried placing @Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") before the class (not that I wanted to extend its scope to the whole file, just to try), and using an underscore in front of the variable name. I would like to know the correct way to suppress that warning in case I'm leaving the parameter reserved for future use, but I don't want to be distracted by the warning.
This warning shows up when I making a commit.

That isn't just a parameter, it's a property.  Try treating it like that.  Or just using "unused"

You can use either approach. It’s up to you and your project team, but make sure to keep one standard across the entire project so that everyone can understand it for future use.
In our project, we use val _context: Context.
